# Need to resize AD Thumbnail for use in other application using c#

Tags: c#, image-resizing

I have read several posts regarding resizing an image to a smaller one while maintaining aspect ration and quality. I only have active directory thumbnails to works from which are 96 x 96. I am able to access the byte array and create a jpeg from it at 484 x 484. The problem is it is very grainy and blurry. What am I missing to improve the quality when increasing the image size.  thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use an image processing library such as ImageSharp: https://github.com/SixLabors/Samples/blob/master/ImageSharp/ResizeImage/Program.cs

Comment: I believe I am actually looking for the HR648x648 user photo in exchange. Trying to create a larger photo from the AD thumbnail will probably not result in a high quality image